# “Unexpected error” on update requests

Tags: themes, updates, core

It needs connectivity to wordpress.org and is timing out.  I am behind a corporate firewall.  I have never had this issue come up before in previous versions.  Why does themes.php need access to wordpress.org and what can I do so it doesn't (or maybe something that will allow me to use my proxy settings).

Adding in error message:

> PHP Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not
>   establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your
>   server administrator.) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ticket\wp-admin\includes\theme.php on line 298

This is definitely new to 3.7.  We have 3.6.1 installed 4-5 times and no issues.  I would have people chopping off my head if they couldn't change their theme.

**Update:** 3.8 fixed a lot of the major issues.  However we still cannot find plugins, find themes or get and of the dashboard feeds.  If anyone has a solution to these - even if it a suggestion for the proxy server, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Navigating WP admin in general tends to trigger multiple external requests, such as fetching news feeds and theme/plugin updates (not counting whatever plugin/themes might be doing on their own).

You can put configuration constants into `wp-config.php` to block external requests completely/partially:

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
define( 'WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', 'api.wordpress.org,*.github.com' );
```

Or configure external requests to use your proxy settings:

```
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', '192.168.84.101');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost, www.example.com, *.wordpress.org');
```

Plus `WP_PROXY_USERNAME` and `WP_PROXY_PASSWORD` for authentication.

Comment: First great feedback.  I will try a few things out and report.  Any idea on the change in 3.7 that triggered the issue?  Also is there a plugin to manage these settings.  I roll out WP sites left and right and would hate to have to change things every time there is a new install or someone upgrades.

Comment: @STing I think it's likely due to [API requests getting forced to use SSL in 3.7](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/25/json-encoding-ssl-api-wordpress-3-7/)

Comment: My server does support SSL.  What do I need to do to make the site call back to https?   This to me seems like a bug.

Comment: @STing since WP chooses between multiple back-ends for HTTP requests this is hard to advise on without hands on debug and better understanding what is going on. I would start with installing [Core Control](http://wordpress.org/plugins/core-control/) and taking a look.

Comment: Ugggg.  So is this an issue with anyone that has SSL installed or just SSL plus firewall?

Comment: Of course the plugins-install needs to get to wordpress.org.  I can't believe there aren't a million complaints on this.

Comment: So let me give update.  None of the settings helped because it needs access to wordpress.org.... I can't turn off SSL on this server because it is used globally (can this weekend for a few mins)...  Also installed 3.6.1 and verified that issue does not exist there... installed the core control on 3.6.1... now need to upgrade to 3.7.1 and when i go to the auto update it says that 3.6.1 is the latest... so will try to do this manually.  Really dumb BUG...

Comment: There aren't a million complains because this is rare issue and typically server configuration issue rather than WordPress one.

Comment: I am a teacher and I used WordPress websites on LAN for students to learn. Blocking http solved my problem of slow dashboard and few other pages. I opt this solution as my server is not having internet connection. and students have to access WordPress installed on server remotely.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with changes in WordPress’ HTTP API. It isn’t fully compatible with cURL anymore.
I am not sure, why *exactly* it happens (there is no context information given, when this error occurs), but you can add a temporary fix.

In a plugin, or at the very end of your `wp-config.php`, add the following lines:

```
add_filter( 'http_api_transports', function()
{
    return array( 'streams' );
});
```

This will disable cURL and make the error message go away without affecting other components on the server.

---

For completeness, here my current cURL details:

```bsh
$ curl --version
curl 7.26.0 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.7
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tf
tp
Features: GSS-Negotiate Largefile NTLM SSL SSPI libz
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not have timeouts but the https://api.wordpress.org requests were getting `500 handshakefailed` errors from the corporate firewall. I discovered that on my Ubuntu 12.04 system, I had failed to install `php5-curl`. Once I installed it and restarted apache2, the problem went away.

Comment: I will double check but pretty sure curl is running.  It is good to know curl is required though.  Also will test out 3.8 and update the question if it is still a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it might be only a network issue. But I've had an issue with the same warning (so it may apply, though it may have several possible reasons) and found a solution *within Wordpress* [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-wordpressorg-11?replies=18), though on localhost. They suggested replacing the files referenced in the error message by the same files from fresh install of the same Wordpress version (just download the .zip file for that version, unpack and copy the file in question).

In my case it was `(path-to-wordpress)/wp-include/update.php`, in your case it would be `(path-to-wordpress)/wp-admin/include/theme.php`. As I understand the issue, some parts of a file where establishing the secure connection is handled went corrupted during an update.