# How to keep WP from using https to get to wordpress.org?

Tags: ssl

See question [“Unexpected error” on update requests](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121334/in-3-7-1-why-is-themes-php-timing-out/121336?noredirect=1#comment170770_121336)

Turning off SSL on the server is not something we can do since we use the server to serve content on other SSL binding servers.  What can I do in WP to make the WP core just use http?  I want all of our admin stuff going to http://api.wordpress.org.

There is an SSL variable - $ssl - that is being read.  How do I set that to FALSE everywhere so that WP doesn't try to use it.  I have no security needs since I am behind proxy/firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to turn off SSL on the server. You need to install an HTTP client method that supports SSL transport.

This has nothing to do with your server supporting SSL as a server. In this case, WordPress is acting like a web-browser, and trying to make an HTTPS connection to WordPress.org, so that you can download files securely.

Typically, you need to reconfigure your PHP installation on the server so as to have CURL and OpenSSL available to PHP. How to do this precisely depends on your hosting service or system.

Comment: I have many other sites on my server that use SSL without an issue.  I am the server admin so I can make whatever changes I want.  I don't mind adding PHP extensions but I just don't understand why WP needs to make a HTTPS connection to wordpress.org - I don't need or want it to.  I have enough one off issues being behind a bulky proxy server and this new one is a pain.  Would like to tell WP that I don't want to use SSL when connecting to their site.

Comment: With the new automatic updates feature in 3.7 (for minor releases), it's important that you connect to the WordPress.org API securely, so as to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks. If somebody could get between your systems and the WordPress.org systems, and pretend to be WordPress.org, then they could, in theory, automatically upload malware to sites using the auto-updates feature. Thus, it will only support SSL connections to prevent this. This is enforced on the api.wordpress.org side too, so not using HTTPS connections here is no longer an option.

Comment: Well in a word... that sucks... but I appreciate the knowledge and insight.  I have WP implementations on the web and I totally understand the need for the security there.  But some of the functionality I have loved will be lost.  I don't want to have to have a web connection to switch themes.  I work all the time off the grid.  I will make sure that I have curl and openssl up and report back in case others are having the issue - to see if that helps.

Comment: You don't need a connection to WordPress.org to switch themes, but you need one to browse or download new themes from there.

Comment: In 3.7.1 I am timing out trying to switch themes on my server - going to themes.php.  This does not happen on any earlier version.  Also all of the warning messages are pointed at lines looking for $ssl set to true/on.

Comment: That's because it's trying to check for theme-updates from the WordPress.org API when you visit that page. If it could get the proper response, then it would cache that and not ask again for 12 hours. Since it can't get that response, it will keep trying until it does.

Comment: Also, earlier versions than 3.7 did not require HTTPS connections. It was decided to implement them for security in 3.7. The number of PHP installs without HTTPS capabilities was determined to be very small in real-world hosting. On most Linux distributions, the php-curl and openssl extensions are installed in the system by default when php is installed. Unless you have a custom built PHP or some such thing, it's very unusual and rare to not have curl and ssl support in PHP nowadays.

Comment: Yea I just verified both curl and openssl are running... I have set the timeouts way way high and now all of the pages come up (themes.php, import.php, install-plugin.php) but they take a long long time to load.  I don't understand why themes.php is reaching out to wordpress.org or cares if I am https or not.  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: It's hitting the API to check for theme updates. I do not know about your timing issues, as the WordPress.org API servers are quite snappy to respond to most requests.

Comment: So how do you change themes now if you don't have an internet connection - or in my case I am behind a very slow corporate proxy server (and even slower with SSL)?  I do not understand the point of forced updates.  I rather initiate my interaction with WP.  This to me is a bug.  Until WP has a better way to handle the admin page and user roles in its core I don't want to have my other admins changing stuff because they see updates...

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04 host (behind a corporate firewall), the problem was that php5-curl was not installed. I installed it and WP was then able to make https requests to api.wordpress.org. Before this the https requests would get "500 handshakefailed" errors (which I was able to see by using tcpdump).